# Limit of multiple inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

What is the limit of multiple inheritance in C++? i.e, how many classes can a class inherit from? Is it implementation dependent or is there a constraint placed on the number of classes you can inherit from in multiple inheritance?

Comment: The language standard probably stipulates a lower bound.  But is this really going to be an issue in practice?

Comment: Chances are very high that if you are inheriting from more than 1 non-abstract base class, you have a severe design problem.

Comment: Its not about a design flaw or a case of judgement. I don't even work with C++. A curious kid happens to ask me this and I don't really have an answer. So somebody tell me..

Comment: There is what the standard allows (both Mat and M.M. have stated that), but then there is what is practical.  Multiple inheritance of non-abstract base classes is messy, and 95% of the time should be avoided.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's implementation defined. C++11 gives recommended minimums in the *Implementation quantities* section of the standard:

> — Direct and indirect base classes [16 384].
>   — Direct base classes for a single class [1 024].
>   [...]
>   — Direct and indirect virtual bases of a class [1 024].

I'd say that's pretty generous.

Comment: Could you please refer or attach to the document this information is stated? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents @dochoex. This non-official site is good for browsing in my opinion: http://eel.is/c++draft/#intro. Also cppreference has good stuff. Official github: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft

Answer (score 5):

Per §10.1:

> <sup>1</sup> A class can be derived from any number of base classes. [*Note*: The use of more than one direct base class
>   is often called multiple inheritance. —*end note* ]

Everything else depends on compiler's implementation and limitations.